# Make Script Run Faster Using Auto Hot Key

Tags: autohotkey

I need to make the script run faster. Could anyone help me out? Any key that I can make the script run faster? Below is my working code.
I Had tried using `Setbatchlines, -1` but that's not working.

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
#WinActivateForce
Setbatchlines, -1

Run,Desk.cpl
SetTimer, Check, 500
return

Check:

IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
{
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinWait, Screen Resolution
WinActivate, Screen Resolution
WinWaitActive, Screen Resolution
ControlFocus, ComboBox3, Screen Resolution
Send, {Tab}{Space}
}
else
{
IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
{
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinWait, Screen Resolution
WinActivate, Screen Resolution
WinWaitActive, Screen Resolution
ControlFocus, ComboBox2, Screen Resolution
Send, {Tab}{Space}
}
}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
{
WinActivate
SendMessage, 0x1330, 1,, SysTabControl321, ahk_class #32770
}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
{
WinActivate
Sleep 1230
Control, ChooseString, True Color (32 bit), ComboBox2, ahk_class #32770
Sleep 1230
}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770 
{
WinActivate
ControlClick, &Apply, ahk_class #32770
}

IfWinExist,Display Settings 
{
WinActivate
ControlClick, &Yes,Display Settings 
}

IfWinExist, ahk_class #32770  
{
WinActivate
ControlClick,OK, ahk_class #32770
}

IfWinActive, Screen Resolution 
{
WinActivate
ControlClick, OK, Screen Resolution
}

IfWinNotExist, Screen Resolution
{
ExitApp
return
}
```

Comment: What about SetTimer ?

Comment: Replace 500 with a lower value.

Comment: Yeah i had used Set timer in my code , the thing is when i try to reduce the timer less than 500 , windows are getting closed without executing the code :( In my code i had used Windows concept... I dont know why if i reduce the timer the code not executing

Comment: Any Other Option that we can make script run Faster ?? Any Shortcut Hot Key for that ???

Answer (score 1):

Increase keyboard and mouse speed by adding

```
setKeyDelay, 0
setMouseDelay, 0
```

in the top section of your script.

Comment: Will this code creates any trouble with performance ???  SetTitleMatchMode, 2                                                                                                    WinWait, Screen Resolution
WinActivate, Screen Resolution
WinWaitActive, Screen Resolution

Comment: @manikanth I think it doesnt matter where exactly you put it, but  it has to be before that very first `return`.

Comment: and no it shouldnt create any trouble. why dont you try it out? :)

Comment: No I mean with the code i had added in the 2nd comment not with the code which you had given :)